# deep copying the pandas dataframe into a list (including index)

Tags: python, list, pandas, indexing

I have a pandas dataframe df

```
    column1
2     1
3     2
8     3
10    4
45    5
```

I wanna convert this column1 of pandas dataframe into a list x , and I also want the index to be the index of the list as well

so that if i call x[2]

it should return 1

I tried

```
x = df['column1'].values
```

But the list index got reset.

I am looking for an answer, I will appreciate your time and effort to help me.

Comment: Index of the list? What do you mean? You can't index a Python list besides positionally.

Answer (score 1):

Python list has contiguous index, it can't have holes in the index range.

The only way possible to achieve your goal is to fill the original series with `nan` for every hole, making a contiguous index:

```
In [29]: df.column1.reindex(np.arange(df.index.max()+1)).tolist()
Out[29]: 
[nan,
 nan,
 1.0,
 2.0,
 nan,
 nan,
 nan,
 nan,
 3.0,
 nan,
 4.0,
 nan,
 nan,
 nan,
 nan,
 nan,
 ....
```

If you can use a `dict`, then the following approach is preferable:

```
In [35]: df.column1.to_dict()
Out[35]: {2: 1, 3: 2, 8: 3, 10: 4, 45: 5}
```

Comment: I want to use that list to build a model and I have to partition the training and test data based on the index only as its very crucial in the business context. any suggestion pleasse